# How to set up Spring boot 3 security config proper?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm trying to integrate the updated Spring Security in my project, instead of using the deprecated `extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. I've set up a good system in which the user gets authenticated (`User` implements `UserDetails` - I am using Hibernate) and a token gets generated. I get a 200 on this login and receive a token. This authetication part works fine.

Now the problem is that my users have roles (like `ADMIN`, `USER`, ...) These roles are added to the generated token. My controllers get the `@PreAuthorize` annotation. The request cannot pass these annotation and get a forbidden. When I don't use the `@PreAuthorize`, the requests get validated with the token.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private RSAKey rsaKey;
    private final DefaultUserDetailsService defaultUserDetailsService;
    
    public SecurityConfig(DefaultUserDetailsService defaultUserDetailsService) {
        this.defaultUserDetailsService = defaultUserDetailsService;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
    return http 
               .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
               .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
               .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                   .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                   .anyRequest().authenticated()
               )            
               .userDetailsService(defaultUserDetailsService)
               .sessionManagement(session ->  session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
               .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
               .headers(headers -> headers
                   .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
               )
               .httpBasic(withDefaults())
               .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        rsaKey = Jwks.generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }
    
    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() throws JOSEException {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaKey.toRSAPublicKey()).build();
   }
    
    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwks) {
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
        
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET","POST","DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("Authorization","Content-Type"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**",configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

```java
@Component
public class KeyGeneratorUtils {

    private KeyGeneratorUtils() {}

    static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Jwks {
       private Jwks() {}

        public static RSAKey generateRsa() {
            KeyPair keyPair = KeyGeneratorUtils.generateRsaKey();
            RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
            RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
            return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                    .privateKey(privateKey)
                    .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .build();
        }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class DefaultTokenService implements TokenService {
    private final JwtEncoder encoder;

    public DefaultTokenService(JwtEncoder encoder) {
        this.encoder = encoder;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        String scope = authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        
        System.out.println("scope: " + scope);
        
        JwtClaimsSet claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder()
                .issuer("self")
                .issuedAt(now)
                .expiresAt(now.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS))
                .subject(authentication.getName())
                .claim("scope", scope)
                .build();
        return this.encoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(claims)).getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

```java
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails{
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      private final Long id;
      private final String username;
      private final String riziv;
      private final boolean verified;
      @JsonIgnore
      private final String password;
      private final Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;
    
        public UserDetailsImpl(Long id, String username, String riziv, String password,
                Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, boolean verified) {
                this.id = id;
                this.username = username;
                this.riziv = riziv;
                this.password = password;
                this.authorities = authorities;
                this.verified = verified;
            }

        public static UserDetailsImpl build(AuthUser authUser) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authUser.getRol().toString()));
          
            
            return new UserDetailsImpl(
                    authUser.getId(),
                    authUser.getUsername(),
                    authUser.getRiziv(),
                    authUser.getPassword(),
                    authorities, authUser.isVerified());
        }
        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return authorities;
        }
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public boolean isVerified() {
            return verified;
        }
        public String getRiziv() {
            return riziv;
        }
        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o)
                return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
                return false;
            UserDetailsImpl klant = (UserDetailsImpl) o;
            return Objects.equals(id, klant.id);
        }

}
```

```java
@Service
public class DefaultUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final AuthUserService authUserService;
    
    public DefaultUserDetailsService(AuthUserService authUserService) {
        this.authUserService = authUserService;
    }


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        AuthUser authUser = authUserService.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " + username));

        return UserDetailsImpl.build(authUser);
    }

}
```

```java
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('USER', 'ADMIN')")
```

I am making a configuration mistake somewhere, but I cannot seem to find it. Spring docs are very very hard to figure out, but I have been reading them relentlessly. There is also not a lot of clear information on these topics yet. I can find youtube videos tutorials and some related topics, but they only explain small parts, never a full setup.

I have added below my `securityConfig`, `KeyGenerator`, `Jwks` and `tokengenerate` service. I also just added the `Userdetailsimpl` and service. I build my `userdetailsImpl` out of a user with a static build method. It might seem a strange construction but it works, it is because I did the security last and didn't think of it before. Also I added an example of my `@Preauthorize`.

I am very close and this could be a good example for other users trying to implement this, because I seem not te able to find an example somewhere.Does anyone have experience with setting the Spring Boot 3 security up and can they tell me how I am misconfiguring? Why is my role not getting 'read' by the `@PreAuthorize`?

Comment: The answer depends upon how are you using PreAuthorize. Are you using hasRole/hasAnyRole to check the roles or hasAuthority/hasAnyAuthority?
The hasRole method appends ROLE_ as prefix to whatever is passed into it as value. Moreover it also depends upon how have you implemented your getAuthorities method for User Model implementing UserDetails from Spring Security. I think you should add those implementations as well so that a clear picture can be generated on the issue.

Comment: I added the userDetailsImpl as you asked. I use the hasAnyRole annotation. I checked my getAuthorities method with a lot of console prints at the time and it seems to be doing is job correct.

Comment: I have updated my answer and you can use the solution you desire to fix the problem. In my opinion you should go for second approach with Custom Converter since it gives you more flexibility in terms of using scopes. During console print try using the authentication object instead of user object(if not already using this approach).  authentication.getAuthorities() prefixes SCOPE_ to all the role name values by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay so here's the thing, since you're implementing resource server, the class:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter
```

is the one responsible for converting your scopes inside JWT token to granted authorities.
Now, this class prepends all the authorities with **`SCOPE_`** prefix.

Since you're using

```java
hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'USER',...)
```

this method internally invokes,

```java
hasAnyAuthorityName(defaultRolePrefix, roleName)
```

method with the `defaultRolePrefix` as `ROLE_` and the `roleName` as your passed in value(s).

Internal implementation:

```java
@Override
public final boolean hasAnyRole(String... roles) {
    return hasAnyAuthorityName(this.defaultRolePrefix, roles);
}

@Override
public final boolean hasAnyAuthority(String... authorities) {
    return hasAnyAuthorityName(null, authorities);
}
```

On the other hand, the **`hasAnyAuthority`** method makes a call to the same method but with **`null` passed in to the `defaultRolePrefix`**.

Now since you're using:

```java
.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
```

in security config, it is using the default `AuthenticationConverter` for your JWT token which is

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationConverter
```

which further invokes

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter
```

As per the implementation in `JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter`, all the scopes in your JWT token are prefixed by **`SCOPE_`** as I mentioned earlier.

Now assuming your granted authorities return **`ADMIN`** as one of the roles. Once you add it to your ***`scope`*** in JWT, the default converter will return **`SCOPE_ADMIN`** as an authority and similarly if you return **`ROLE_ADMIN`** in the scope, it will be converted to **`SCOPE_ROLE_ADMIN`** by default.

The `JwtAuthenticationConverter` class returns an instance of

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken
```

So, it can be fixed in following ways:

Either, use `hasAnyAuthority` to check the authorities by appending `SCOPE_` to the role names you have set in scope.
If your role name is **`ADMIN`** or **`ROLE_ADMIN`** you should use

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('SCOPE_ADMIN')")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('SCOPE_ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

and so on.
If you want to use `hasAnyRole` check then you must use

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_SCOPE_ADMIN')")
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ROLE_SCOPE_ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

for **`ADMIN`** and **`ROLE_ADMIN`** values respectively.

Or, implement a custom authority converter and pass it to the `oauth2ResourceServer` in security config as follows,

**Example Custom Converter**

```java
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Collections;

@Component
public class JwtCustomAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {
    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        Collection<String> splitScopes = Arrays.asList(jwt.getClaim("scope").split(" "));
        for (String authority : splitScopes) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority));
        }
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }
}
```

Then update your Spring Security config as:

```java
@Bean 
JwtCustomAuthoritiesConverter jwtCustomAuthoritiesConverter;

@Bean
JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter(){
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtCustomAuthoritiesConverter);
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}

...

http.oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) ->
                        oauth2.jwt((jwt) -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter()))
...
```

With the second option you can use your role names the way you want to in JWT token and the

```java
hasAnyRole('ADMIN')
```

check should get `ROLE_ADMIN` for `ADMIN` scope instead of `ROLE_SCOPE_ADMIN` which is the case now.